# Can't start the visulal c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr, static-libraries, static-linking

I write clr visual c++ program and I have one problem. I use static library .lib in my solution as one of the projects. I use objects from this library in my application. If I write this line

```
CLogger *log = new CLogger(new CFileLog("logger.txt"));
```

I can't start the application. It's loading in msvcr100d.dll and don't start. How solve this problem?

Comment: you could get the .dll file and post it in your project file

Comment: @DevangJayachandran, unfortunatly I can't, because my library can be used as static lib only

Comment: get the library's source code and compile it with yours?